# "Error: Parameter 1 required" when attempting to set a listener on onBeforeRequest

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrequest

background.js :

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse)
    {
        console.log(request.filter)
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(request.func, request.filter, ["blocking"]);
    }
);
```

content script:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest(
    {
        func: requestInterceptor,
        filter: requestFilter
    }
);
```

The line `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(request.func, request.filter, ["blocking"]);` is triggering the following error:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Error: Parameter 1 is required.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is `request.func` undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On message passing, requests are JSON-serialized.
Functions are not serializable, so they're not sent.

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest( {
    func: requestInterceptor,    // Function
    filter: requestFilter        // Array of strings
});
```

is received as

```
{
    filter: requestFilter
}
```

Move the function logic to the background page.
If you want to add a [`webRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html) event listener from the content script, pass all necessary (JSON-serializable) data to the background page using [`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest). The receiver (background), also gets a [`MessageSender`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#type-MessageSender) type, which can be used to read the [`tab`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab) of the origin (which supplies all necessary information, including the tabId).